# how to to display and search between date sharepoint document library in web part

Tags: csom, visual-web-part

hi every one,
             i am trying to display all document library item in gridview using web part with a linkFileName column. below is my code.

```
try
{
    using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("URL"))
    {
        context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
        context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");
        Web webObj = context.Web;
        List listObj = webObj.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
        CamlQuery camlquery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(1000000);
        ListItemCollection listitemcoll = listObj.GetItems(camlquery);
        context.Load(listitemcoll);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        //4/25/2013 12:00:00 PM
        if (listitemcoll.Count != 0)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dRow;

            DataColumn dcNotificationNumber = new DataColumn("Notification_x0020_Number");
            dcNotificationNumber.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

            DataColumn dcSubject = new DataColumn("Subject");
            dcSubject.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

            DataColumn dcCreated = new DataColumn("Created");
            dcCreated.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            DataColumn dclink = new DataColumn("LinkFilename");
            dclink.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

            dt.Columns.Add(dcNotificationNumber);
            dt.Columns.Add(dcSubject);
            dt.Columns.Add(dcCreated);
            dt.Columns.Add(dclink);

            foreach (ListItem item in listitemcoll)
            {
                dRow = dt.NewRow();
                dRow["Notification_x0020_Number"] = item["Notification_x0020_Number"];
                dRow["Subject"] = item["Subject"];
                dRow["Created"] = item["Created"];
                //string linkFileName = file.Item["LinkFilename"] as string;
                // dRow["LinkFilename"] = item["LinkFilename"];
                string fileurl = (string)item["FileRef"];
                dRow[fileurl]=item[fileurl];
                dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            //write messages to client - no data is present
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: You are not actually using "URL" as parameter to `ClientContext()` right?

Comment: Hi the gridview is of Window form based application or web based application?

Comment: @helb the problem is when i want to display a linkfile name it throws error

Comment: @Sunilsahu it is webpart , web base.

Comment: i was asking about the control you used in webpart

Comment: @Sunilsahu i am using webbase gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi updated the code try to verify

```
try
{
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("URL"))
{
    context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");
    Web webObj = context.Web;
    List listObj = webObj.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
    CamlQuery camlquery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(1000000);
    ListItemCollection listitemcoll = listObj.GetItems(camlquery);
    context.Load(listitemcoll);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    //4/25/2013 12:00:00 PM
    if (listitemcoll.Count != 0)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dRow;

        DataColumn dcNotificationNumber = new DataColumn("Notification_x0020_Number");
        dcNotificationNumber.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

        DataColumn dcSubject = new DataColumn("Subject");
        dcSubject.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

        DataColumn dcCreated = new DataColumn("Created");
        dcCreated.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        DataColumn dclink = new DataColumn("LinkFilename");
        dclink.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

        dt.Columns.Add(dcNotificationNumber);
        dt.Columns.Add(dcSubject);
        dt.Columns.Add(dcCreated);
        dt.Columns.Add(dclink);

        foreach (ListItem item in listitemcoll)
        {
            dRow = dt.NewRow();
            dRow["Notification_x0020_Number"] = item["Notification_x0020_Number"];
            dRow["Subject"] = item["Subject"];
            dRow["Created"] = item["Created"];
            //string linkFileName = file.Item["LinkFilename"] as string;
            // dRow["LinkFilename"] = item["LinkFilename"];
            //string fileurl = (string)item["FileRef"];
            dRow["LinkFilename"]=Convert.ToString(item["FileRef"]);
            dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

 //If it is gridview and not datagrid then uncomment below line
//dataGridView1.Databind();
    }
    else
    {
        //write messages to client - no data is present
    }
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  throw ex;
}
```

Comment: thats works perfectly. but if i want to click on that link and want to download it. then what need to do ?

Comment: You can refer the https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47729/link-to-download-a-copy-from-a-document-library