# Document ID - open a document in SharePoint or download a document

Tags: sharepoint-online, pdf, document-id, file-download

is it possible to use a link with parameters when using Document ID to set whether the document opens in SharePoint or downloads when the link is clicked?
I am currently using /_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=DOCID, but not all documents open in SharePoint (e.g. a PDF document is downloaded immediately).
Is it possible to somehow force the download or opening of the document?

If not, is there a URL that would allow the document to be downloaded based on the Document ID? I only found /_layouts/download.aspx but couldn't find documentation for it or a parameter that supports Document ID.

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Use the “Copy link” Option and append “&download=1” Frame the download link to force Download instead of Open.

You can use the "Copy Link" option and append “?web=1” to force open.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I think that if I use copy link, I will lose the benefits of Document ID (keeping the link when moving the file).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the Edge browser unfortunately.  We have tried several approaches, eg **1)**  `&download=1`  **2)**  `&web=0`   **3)**  `https://<tenant-name>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=<document-url>`.  We have been googling and testing for hours but can't find a solution to the problem "How to force download document via link in SharePoint Online".

Comment: update and fyi, solution is here:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/121124